# JavaScript Promises Not Returning Object

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js

I have an issue where I am using Sequelize to run a query and within the first then statment return the object and then run a query on a different table. After that query is run I have an additional then statement that should pass the returned objects to be able to access in my view. Unfortunately, the second query does not return an object as the console log returns `undefined` for the second log (Check `console.log(member)`). Any reason why this is happening or what I am doing wrong? The queries come back with the right statements.

```
appRoutes.route('/settings/add-users')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.Organization.find({
            where: {
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            }, attributes: ['organizationId', 'organizationName','admin','members']
        }).then(function(organization, member){
            models.Member.findAll({
                where: {
                    organizationId: organization.organizationId
                }, attributes: ['memberEmail']
            });
            return organization;
        }).then(function(organization, member){

            console.log(organization);
            console.log(member);
            res.render('pages/app/add-users.hbs',{
                user: req.user,
                organization: organization,
                member: member
            });
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
```

Comment: That's because the result of the resolved value of the second promise is the return value of the callback. In this case, it's `organization`. Perhaps you wanted to return `models.member.findAll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise can only resolve to a single value. You are returning `organization` again from your then, so the next `then` gets that as its value. You can use an object to achieve the behaviour you want.

```
appRoutes.route('/settings/add-users')

    .get(function(req, res){
        var organization;

        models.Organization.find({
            where: {
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            }, attributes: ['organizationId', 'organizationName','admin','members']
        }).then(function(_organization){
            organization = _organization;
            return models.Member.findAll({
                where: {
                    organizationId: organization.organizationId
                }, attributes: ['memberEmail']
            });
        }).then(function(member){

            console.log(organization);
            console.log(member);
            res.render('pages/app/add-users.hbs',{
                user: req.user,
                organization: organization,
                member: member
            });
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It appears that an error is thrown at the `return` object where there is a `,` after `organization,`. Unexpected token. Any thoughts on why this occurred?

Comment: @cphill Oh my bad, I assumed that you were doing this in a recent version of node.js. That is an [ES6 only syntax](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html) ( it is shorthand for `organization: organization` ). I will edit the answer.

Comment: No worries! although I don't believe this solution worked because I receive `[object Promise]` as the logged object. I'm curious if the location of the log is the reason why that is happening. I notice that my `models.Member.findAll` query is being triggered after the console log of `results.members` Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @cphill You're right, I missed something let me start over.

Comment: @cphill My new answer should work for you, although I don't find the outer scoped `organization` variable particularly nice. That is how I typically get around this issue.

Comment: I agree, but it works for now. Thank you for your help!